# Dynamic roles in Schema Permissons

Tags: iccube

**use-case**

All our roles in icCube give only access to one client schema. A user can only have one role. For some users though, I would like to give access to a DEMO domain as well, depending on their e-mail.

**my attempt**

Considering that the DEMO domain is called "Sales (Demo)", I try to add the following code to each user role:

```
-- Give access to the client domain
+ <specific client domain> 


+schema [Sales (Demo)]
:schema [Sales (Demo)]

create function isAbc(username_) as instr(username_,'@') > 0 and mid(username_,instr(username_,'@'),100)= '@abc.com'

#IF isAbc(username())

+cube R Sales

#ELSE

-all

#ENDIF
```

**resulting error, why?**

This code breaks with an error in the Loaded Schemas:

```
[ROLES_UNEXPECTED_ERROR] isAbc() : [OLAP_MDX_FUNCTION_UNRESOLVED] isAbc() : the function (isAbc) does not exist location:
```

**debugging in MDX IDE**

When I test the function in the MDX IDE, it seems to work though:

```
with
   function isAbc(username_) as instr(username_,'@') > 0 and mid(username_,instr(username_,'@'),100)= '@abc.com'
   member measures.a as isAbc('aturing@abc.com')
   member measures.b as isAbc('pstolk@google.com')
   member measures.c as isAbc('admin')
select {a,b,c} on 0
from sales
```

Result:

|  | All-M |
| --- | --- |
| a | true |
| b | false |
| c | false |

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the function `isAbc()` cannot be used in the preprocessing statements `#IF`. It's more likely these preprocessing statements are evaluated first to extract the actual list of statements to execute to define the permissions.

As a workaround, you'll need to write the function code inside the `#IF` statement:

```
#IF instr(username(),'@') > 0 and mid(username(),instr(username(),'@'),100)= '@abc.com'
...
#ENDIF
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, even with the suggestion you give. A username 'aturing@abc.com' that has this role definition, still can;t get access to the demo cube Sales.  Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Arthur, look at the workaround that is copy/pasting the isAbc() function code. What is the new role definition and the error you get? Otherwise better to contact the icCube support directly.